# Is there an area of maths in which a group of symmetries of a closed curve in a space is studied? For any closed smooth enough curve that is

Tags: group-theory, curves, calculus-of-variations, symmetry

I have this idea of using groups to study closed curves and nearby symmetries I.e slight deformations of a curve yielding a bunch of symmetries. The goal is to detect the "nearby" symmetries of a curve and to be able to find the existing symmetries of a curve.

I want to know if it is moot/ if someone has already done it?

I am also thinking of using a tad bit of variational calculus for some extra parts of it. Invariably someone will have done it, I am just hoping someone hasn't.

EDIT:

To clarify the deformations are very exactly chosen to remove symmetry breaking bumps on loops etc, the goal is to, given a closed nice enough loop: To know its symmetries and to detect the symmetries that don't exist but could exist with a deformation excising the symmetry breaking bumps.

I have some additional ideas about representing the loop in polar coords being periodic in angle coords and just excising noisy terms that way although that is something I haven't investigated very much, its more of an adumbrated untouched concept for now.

Comment: "symmetries" generally means operations that leave an object unchanged, so I'm not sure how you are going to treat deformations as symmetries.

Comment: Deformations tend to destroy symmetries, not add them.

Comment: Sorry for the misphrasing. The deformation wouldn't be a symmetry I am trying to detect nearby symmetries, i.e a circle with one pimple/bump on it has one reflective symmetry but you remove the symmetry i.e deform the bump away and suddenly symmetries go up.

Comment: The goal is to detect symmetries that are broken by certain features of the loop and to be able to automatically just remove the  features and thus gain the symmetries.

Comment: I am thinking of defining any closed loop in cartesian space as a loop in polar space and then saying it is periodic in angle and then doing fourier stuff to remove high noise terms which arent regular although that might be naive.

Comment: Deformations tend to hurt symmetries only if the deformation is applied to a terribly symmetric object and the deformation isnt engineered for symmetry increase, I am using deformation which linguistically has connotations but I mean it in the math sense of deformation which can very much add symmetry

Comment: Symmetries are studied in Lie theory, closed curves to some extend in algebraic geometry, depending on how and where you define curves, and deformations might be subject to the calculus of variations, which closes the circle to Lie theory.